# Track Google Analytics goals separately for two apps with the same URL after goal completion

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working for a client that has a checkout flow that looks like this:

`example.com/subscribe?app=app1` --> *buys* --> `example.com/dashboard`

or

`example.com/subscribe?app=app2` --> *buys* --> `example.com/dashboard`

I'd like to set up separate goals, one for app1, and one for app2. However, I'm running into several issues.

1. Both apps land on the same goal page.
2. The goal page is not a goal specific page, so you could land on /dashboard and it should not count as a conversion.
3. I don't have access to change the behavior of this application. I either need to do the tracking somehow in Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager.

What would be the best way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also struggling with this same issue. What I've tried is to set up destination goals in GA and set funnels for them - so each goal would have the same 'thank you' page, but have a different URL as a goal funnel. Not sure if you have already tried this - hope it is helpful to you. 
I'm trying to figure out a way to do this with GTM at the moment, I will let you know if I come up with anything. And please let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if you do what I said before, then you can see the difference in conversions in the Funnel Visualization report - but not the normal Goals report - in GA. Both goals will still fire every time someone lands on the thank you page as the goals don't take the funnel into account for whatever reason. So your goal completions will be inaccurate (doubled), but the funnel visualization will show the split accurately :)